# "crontab -e" failing under Monterey with "$EDITOR: No such file or directory"

Tags: terminal, monterey, cron

I was hoping for a little guidance with a problem that has me beaten.

I want to use cronjobs on a Mac Mini running macOS Monterey, but it is not behaving as it does on other machines I have running Debian.

When I run `crontab -l`, I get what you would expect, in this case;

```
# m  h  dom mon dow   command
```

which is how I left it a few versions of macOS ago.

However, when I run `crontab -e`, I get the rather more unexpected;

```
crontab: $EDITOR: No such file or directory
crontab: "$EDITOR" exited with status 1
```

The `EDITOR` variable is set to `/usr/local/bin/nvim`, and `nvim` works perfectly as I am using it now to draft this post.

The only things a broad Google search has shown me are:

1. I needed to ensure that `cron` was granted Full Disk Access in macOS Security settings

and:

2. that this does not seem to be a normal issue people have encountered.

Could someone point me towards a solution, please?

Comment: Try another editor maybe e.g. export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vi

Comment: I did try vim and vi and the result was the same

Comment: What exact command are you running to create EDITOR?

Comment: What does "export | grep EDITOR" say?

Comment: @mmmmmm Now I‘m curious: why does this matter?

Comment: @mmmmmm See my answer below. It's not a path issue, the variable assignment (or rather the shell quoting used when assigning it) was just wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The error message you get indicates that the `EDITOR` variable is set to the literal value `$EDITOR`:

```
$ EDITOR='$EDITOR' crontab -e
crontab: $EDITOR: No such file or directory
crontab: "$EDITOR" exited with status 1
```

To fix run

```
export EDITOR=/usr/local/bin/nvim
export VISUAL="$EDITOR"
/usr/bin/crontab -e
```

and check the init files of your shell for the wrong definition.

Comment: Sadly, you are mistaken. That is the definition of EDITOR as it appears in my .bashrc.

Comment: ... nevertheless I ran both the lines in your suggestion, but the problem persists. Thanks you for trying though.

Comment: ..... however, I have just edited out the lines refering to export EDITOR and export VISUAL and all now works. If these variables are blank then it works? Odd that this is not a problem under Linux. Anyway I will ponder on the facts, but your solution turned out to work, so thank you very much. I am very grateful.

Comment: @keith56 Glad it works now, but still wonder what exactly is going on here. I set EDITOR in .bashrc as well, works without problems.

Comment: It was the line after; export EDITOR='nvim' . I had; VISUAL='$EDITOR' , which is acceptble under bash on linux, but bash (and zsh) under macos don't like it. Anyway thank you once again. Keith

Comment: @keith56 `VISUAL='$EDITOR'` is working in neither bash nor zsh, on neither macOS nor Linux. I suspect that `crontab` on macOS uses `VISUAL`, `crontab` on Linux uses `EDITOR`, so the problem only shows on macOS.

Comment: To make it explicit: `VISUAL='$EDITOR'` with single quotes is not what you want. You need double quotes: `VISUAL="$EDITOR"`.

Comment: @nohillside `man crontab` (on macOS) specifies it uses either environment variable.  A short test shows it obeys `VISUAL` first, then `EDITOR`, then `/usr/bin/vi` if neither of those works.  It's the same on your average Linux distro, they're all using Vixie Cron.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR;

setting `$VISUAL` to `/usr/bin/nano` makes the `crontab -e`working for me!

### Details

I ran in a similar issue on Monterey in `zsh` but it was due to `SublimeText` was configured as default editor:

```
echo $EDITOR
# output:
subl -w
```

When trying to edit the crontab of either user or root I got:

```
crontab -e # or
sudo crontab -e

# output
crontab: subl -w: No such file or directory
crontab: "subl -w" exited with status 1
```

Neither solutions from other suggestions worked:

- to change the `$VISUAL` editor variable to `subl -w`
- omitting the `-w`

or

- editing the **sudoers file** via `visudo` helped not (to get `visudo` to work, I had to set both `$EDITOR` and `$VISUAL` to nothing)

```
export EDITOR=""
export VISUAL=""
```

actually the suggested line was already present!

```
Defaults env_keep += "EDITOR VISUAL"
```

##### Possible low level shell path issue

At the end it turns out to be related to the regular $PATH is not to be accessible by the `crontab` command. Even symlinks seemed not to work until I set the $VISUAL setting different from $EDITOR to `/usr/bin/nano`. Then it started working using `nano` with an explicit absolute path.

```
export VISUAL=/usr/bin/nano
```

##### Standard `$EDITOR` Setting can be preserved

For `crontab` usage it is irrelevant if `$EDITOR` is set to `nothing` or `subl -w`, both are suitable!

#### IMPORTANT:

To make these changes permanent you have to put the export lines in your terminal startup file ( `~/.zshrc` or ``~/.profile depending on your setup)

Make sure you granted `Full Disk Access` to `crontab` and `cron` in ``System Preferences```

- #### Giving cron full disk access

  If you are using [[macOS]] [[Catalina]] (or higher) you will also need to give the `cron service` **Full Disk Access**.

  - Go to the System Preferences and select Security & Privacy.
  - In the left-hand column, select `Full Disk Access`, click the`padlock icon`, enter your password and click on the `plus icon` for a file browser to appear.
  - When the file browser appears, press `⌘ ⇧ G` to open the `go to folder dialog` and type: `/usr/sbin/cron`
  - Press `Go` to close the dialog and confirm that `cron` appears in the list of apps that have full disk access in the `Security & Privacy` window.
  - Repeat with `/usr/bin/crontab`